# what does this error code mean?

Tags: android

I am testing an app and I get the error code that says: **`glued tomatoes error`**.

I have looked at the website and it is a gamedeveloper question site.

I have never heard of this. What does it mean?

Comment: Can you show the application log (logcat)?

Comment: As you said you are testing the app, the person who gave you the testing task should know what it means and you just need to mention about this error in the report.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's their own custom message generated when the app gives an exception and/or error. I'd contact the app developer for help on this.